# <algorithm> No such file error

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi

I am working on a Raspberry Pi 2.

I need to use the arduPi library like in this [example](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/raspberry-pi-to-arduino-shields-connection-bridge/).
I followed the installation procedure and I copied the code example.
I tried to compile it with *gcc* but I got the following error:

```
arduPi.h:44:21: fatal error: algorithm: No such file or directory
 #include <algorithm>
```

Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: Not enough information, please explain more about your compilation steps, like file names and compiler command.

Comment: Is this really a C question? the header `algorithm` is a standard C++ header, not a standard C header. If `arduPi.h` is a C++ header file, perhaps you should try to compile using g++ instead.

Comment: Tank you! It was really a compilation problem! I was getting crazy while I didn't noticed that the example was for a C++ file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site very clearly says that the example is a "C++" code:

> arduPi is a C++ library that lets you write programs for Raspberry Pi as if you were writing an arduino program. All the functions in order to control Serial port communications, i2C, SPI and GPIO pins are available using the arduino syntax.

In the example where they build the code they even reference g++ (not gcc):

> g++ -lrt -lpthread MY_PROGRAM.cpp arduPi.o -o MY_PROGRAM

Have you written your own program in C++? if not then you need to handle the C++ header from the example, and wrap i properly, otherwise change your code to C++ (provided you can, most often it is no problem).

Comment: You  don't need to call `g++` directly if you do things right.

Comment: @iharob I'm sure you don't, none the less they do use g++ in the example, which to me is a clear clue that the code is C++ :)

Comment: Yes but the OP problem has to be that they used the wrong extension for the file name, namely *.c* instead of *.cpp*. Because provided they used the correct extension, the program has to compile with `gcc` correctly since *gcc* would call the right compiler.

Comment: @iharob yes that could possibly be one of the OPs problems, unless the OP thought the example was C, and thus wrote his own code in C and not C++, which is often easily converted, in my experience converting to C++ is not always as simple as changing the extension.

Comment: I never said that the code is defined by the file extension, it's just how *gcc* works. Please read it's documentation. I strongly believe that [tag:c++] is a language completely different to [tag:c], as many [tag:c] programmers do.

Comment: @iharob then I'm not sure where you are going with your comment? Possibly I misunderstood you, but we do agree that the OP has written his own code in C (either because he thought the example was in C, or because he added the wrong extension), we cannot say which for sure, but the solution to the problem is to convert his example to C++, or handle the C++ header by his own C++ code which exports the needed parts properly, right?

Comment: It is 100% safe to assume that the OP thought the program was a [tag:c] program, it's also very clear that the OP does not know that `<algorithm>` (and all headers lacking the .h) is a [tag:c++] header. And it's 100% safe to say that the program didn't compile as a [tag:c++] program because the source file had *.c* extension. If the file had the correct extension the program would have compiled. So NO! The problem surely was the file extension, your answer is 100% helpful obviously. But my initial comment holds because *gcc* does use the file extension.

Comment: @iharob I never questioned your initial comment, as you can see :) the only addition I had to your comment, was that the solution could prove to be a little more difficult than changing the extension, not because gcc would not try to compile the code as c++, but because the code in the file might not compile under c++.